# How to check available volume provisioners in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes-volume

Is there a command or script that one can use to see or list enabled/available volume provisioners in a Kubernetes cluster?

We have an on-premise cluster and I came to know the hard way that 'local' provisioner has already been enabled in the cluster. So I am trying to see if there is something we can do upfront and set up a few of the provisioners for use by the containers/applications.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe storage classes?

`kubectl get sc`?

Comment: no, sc would give available storage classes in the cluster. Describing the SC though would provide details about underlying provisioner for that SC.

Answer (score -1):

Came to know that there is no way to know this. Somewhere in the documentation I read that system will error out if the referenced provisioner is not present.